# Understanding first responder behavior

Tags: cocoa, first-responder

From the app delegate, I make a window and set it's contentView to be a view programmatically generated from a plist specification. I then bring the window to front. The window has a toolbar, and when the buttons on the toolbar are pressed, it is supposed to display a different contentView.

I have found that the first content view appears with its topmost text field subview already selected as first responder, but changing the view from the toolbar (it sets contentView on the window) to a different view will not select any of that view's text fields as first responder.

I want to have consistency, so ideally either it would never auto-select a control as first responder or it would always auto-select a control as first responder, but I don't really understand what process is making the control first responder in the first place.

Could somebody please explain what is causing that, so I can either prevent it or try to emulate it when switching views?

Answer (score 3):

hussain Shabbir's answer is on the right track, but misses a few things.

First, setting the window's initial first responder, and then making the same view its first responder, is redundant. The point of the first is to cause the second.

Second, you need to set the window's initial first responder *before making the window visible*:

> Sets a given view as the one that’s made first responder (also called the key view) the first time the window is placed onscreen.

If the window is already visible when you set its initial first responder, nothing will happen.

You need to set the initial first responder *before* you make the window visible for the first time.

The best place to do that is not in code at all—it's in the nib.

[image: Simply drag a connection from the window's initial-first-responder outlet to the view.]

You would then not have either of those lines of code.

Better yet:

> The window has a toolbar, and when the buttons on the toolbar are pressed, it is supposed to display a different contentView.

Have you considered using NSTabView? It handles this automatically (every tab view item has its own initial first responder outlet).

Comment: Since the view is being generated programmatically, I'm going to skip IB... but the rest helped a lot, and I will check NSTabView. I ended up chasing this for a while, and finding that NSWindow's -orderFront: is causing NSView to call -nextValidKeyView. As a test, overriding that to return nil makes the view appear with nothing selected. My next test will be to call it when changing the views, like [[view nextValidKeyView] becomeFirstResponder], so I think I can get either behavior.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time with getting this working. In xcode 7 this doesn't seem to work in storyboards. Is this a bug or is there any obvious reason why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want when you click on different views your textfield should be become first responder,  Then the two lines of code below should work:-
Here on the basis of your condition use these below lines:-

```
[[self window] setInitialFirstResponder:(NSView *)YourTextFieldName];
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:(NSView *)YourTextFieldName];
```

Comment: You don't need to tell the window to make a view first responder if it's the window's initial first responder. You also haven't specified when this code needs to run—or even linked to the documentation for `setInitialFirstResponder:`.

Comment: Yes peter i agreed your point whatever you mentioned through binding. But the same thing i have done programatically:)

Comment: +1 just calling `[self.window makeFirstResponder:self]` in `textDidEndEditing` for a NSTextField subclass prevents the container NSTableView from changing the first responder